# Explicit semi-stable theorem for elliptic curves over $p$-adic fields

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, p-adic-hodge-theory

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0007208.pdf) of Maja Volkov, the authur metions a number called "défaut de semi-stabilité" on page 9. It is defined as $\text{dst}(E)=\frac{12}{\text{pgcd} (12,v_p(\Delta_E))}$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and "pgcd" is the greatest common divisor.

Then the authur says on the next paragraph that if $p>5$ and $E$ has potential good reduction over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then $e=\text{dst}(E)$ is prime to $p$ and $E$ has good reduction on an totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $e$.

So the question is how to prove the two propositions and I want to know if there are some reference about the relations between "défaut de semi-stabilité" and the reduction types of elliptic curves.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More generally, let $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a finite extension with $p\ge5$, and let $E/K$ have potential good reduction. Then you can read off the Kodaira-Neron reduction type from the valuation of the minimal discriminant. This is in Tate's table in Antwerp IV, reproduced in my *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* book (Table 15.1) and many other places. Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer and $v$ the normalized valuation on $K$. Take a minimal Weierstrass equation for $E$, 
$$ E: Y^2 = X^3 + AX + B . $$
To get good reduction, we change variables by
$$ E: Y^2 = X^3 + \pi^{-4r}AX + \pi^{-6r}B \quad\text{with}\quad r = \min\left\{\frac14v(A),\frac16v(B)\right\}. $$
So there is a field of good reduction $K_E^{\text{good}}$ given
by one of $K(A^{1/4})$ or $K(B^{1/6})$, from which one can read off the ramification index $e(K_E^{\text{good}}/K)$. A case-by-case analysis yields complete information, as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\text{Type} & II & III & IV & I_0^* & IV^* &III^* & II^* \\ \hline
v(A) & \ge1 & 1 & \ge1 & =2~\text{or}~\ge2 & \ge3 & 3 & \ge4 \\ \hline
v(B) & 1 & \ge2 & 2 & \ge3~\text{or}~=3 & 4 & \ge5 & 5 \\ \hline
v(\Delta_E) & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
K_E^{\text{good}} & K(\pi^{1/6}) & K(\pi^{1/4}) & K(\pi^{2/6}) & K(\pi^{2/4})=K(\pi^{3/6}) & K(\pi^{4/6}) & K(\pi^{3/4}) & K(\pi^{5/6}) \\ \hline
e(K_E^{\text{good}}/K) & 6 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\ \hline
12/\gcd(12,v(\Delta)) & 6 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I see the table 4.1 on page 365 of your book "advanced topics...". But I’m still a little confused. When we are given an elliptic curve over a p-adic field, and if we have computed its Kodaira-Neron reduction type, so we know its discriminant, its conductor and its behavior of $j$-invariant, but how to know the ramification needed to acquire good reduction? Where the "dst" come from? Sorry to disturb you again.

Comment: @Sssss Since $p\ge5$, WLOG we have $E:y^2=X^3+AX+B$. Each reduction type corresponds to some valuation information on $A$ and $B$. I'll do one example. Type III is $v(A)=1$ and $v(B)\ge2$ to get $v(\Delta)=3$. To get good reduction, we go to $Y^2=X^3+\pi^{-4}AX+\pi^{-6}B$, and we need $v(\pi^{-4}A)=0$, so get good reduction over $\mathbb Q_p(A^{1/4})$. Since $v(A)=1$, the ramification index is $4$. The other cases can be handled similarly. I don't know if there's a simpler way to do all cases simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks! I always enjoy reading both your books and your answers on MO.